# Looping through JavaScript "getElementsByTagName()" object

Tags: javascript, html, object

How can I loop through an object returned from "getElementsByTagName()" on a selector correctly. I can't seem to get it right.

For example, if I have a bunch of divs like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="test1">this is a div</div>
<div class="test2">this is a div</div>
<div class="test1">this is a div</div>
<div class="test2">this is a div</div>
<div class="test1">this is a div</div>
<div class="test2">this is a div</div>
</div>
```

and I want to loop through the results from a "getElementsByTagName()" like this:

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

var divs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
   each = divs[i];
   if (each.classList.contains("test2")) {
    this.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

and here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Yzv/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined`

Try:

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

var divs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
   each = divs[i];
   if (each.classList.contains("test2")) {
    each.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Yzv/2/)

Comment: If you put a `console.log(this);` you'll see that `this` is the Window object, which has no style property.

Answer (score 4):

`each.style.display = "none";` would work instead of `this`

`this` refers to the global object, and not to the element being iterated in your loop.

Here is corrected fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Yzv/4/

Answer (score 3):

Less code solution:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div');
[].forEach.call(divs, function (div) {
    if (div.classList.contains('test2')) div.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  `this.style.display = "none";` to `each.style.display = "none"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @aj8uppal How does this not answer the question?

Comment: I agree it's a bit sparse but that's not a reason to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZffWg/

These are the main changed I've made

```
for (i in divs) {
    if (divs[i].className.indexOf("test2") > -1) {
        divs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I removed the `i=0` and so the loop runs on the array index itself.

I also used `className` instead of `classList` for better cross-platform compatibility

Answer (score -1):

```js
let divs_in_wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper div');
divs_in_wrapper.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
  if (item.classList.contains("test2")) {
    item.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test1">this is a div</div>
  <div class="test2">this is a div class test2</div>
  <div class="test1">this is a div</div>
  <div class="test2">this is a div class test2</div>
  <div class="test1">this is a div</div>
  <div class="test2">this is a div class test2</div>
</div>
<div class="test2">this is outside a div</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).